# error when importing vincent into Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vincent

Any idea why I cannot import vincent?

[image: -3]

Comment: Did you `pip install vincent`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

pip install vincent

Like I do it here in my [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoGrh.png)

Comment: Receiving an error:
Collecting pandas (from vincent)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000284DA714898>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/

Wondering if it is blocked by my company - any tricks to address ip constraints?